# Azure DevOps: Cannot see option to Copy Test Plan

Tags: azure-devops, test-plan, azure-devops-server-2020

I cannot seem to find the settings dots (three dots) on my test plan as shown by Microsoft:

My Screen:
[image: My screen with missing settings icons]

Microsoft Help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2020?view=azure-devops#test-plans

[image: Microsoft Docs]

Am I missing something? This was working on TFS 2018 before migrating to Azure DevOps. This all is On-Prem.

Comment: Hi @Hassan Gulzar. Is there any update about this ticket? Please check if the Basic + Test Plans role could solve this issue. Feel free to let me know if the answer could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could navigate to `Access levels` and assign the `Basic + Test Plans` role to the target user.

[image]

Then you could see the option in the Test Plan Page.

[image]

Here is a doc about the [required permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-a-test-plan?view=azure-devops-2020#access-level).